# How I can play Age of Empires 2 HD on LAN?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

I seen some videos that doesn't tell you anything about it... I just want to play AOE2HD with friends without internet using the LAN like old times.

If you know any method to achieve it but you need internet via tungle/hamachi etc post it anyway any help is welcome.

Comment: Is this the steam version or another version?  The steam version has good support for playing online.  We considered it worth the cost to buy it on steam, given that it makes it as simple as click -> join game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot play Age of Empires II HD on LAN. To start a multiplayer match you **require an internet connection**.

The only way to have a match is to connect via the Lobby Browser, which requires you to be logged in with Steam. Once you have started a match, it will use the players IP addresses to determine how they are connected. If all players are on the same router, it will act as a LAN game, and not send data over the internet.

There are [very](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/discussions/0/527274088391554427/), [very](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/discussions/0/35222218782286092/), [many](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/discussions/2/371918937278101716/) threads on Steam supporting this.

Below, trying to start Multiplayer when not connected to internet:
[image]

And with internet:
[image]

Comment: Now i get it! Thx!

Comment: You are only buying [Microsoft's illusion](https://www.ageofempires.com/news/how-to-host-a-lan-game-in-aoe-ii-hd/) that you can play on LAN. **You cannot play AOE2 on LAN**. The moment you need Internet it is no longer LAN. Let's be precise please.